# wrong distance between 2 GPS points - android

Tags: android, gps, distance

I want to get the distance between 2 points, one is getted by GPS and the second is fix. I get a result, but the distance is 40 km but it should be around 25 km and I can't find another formula. Please help me to fix the problem.

btnShowLocation = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);

```
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                //Objekt in der Klasse erzeugen
                gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());

                //überprüfen, ob GPS aktiv ist
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deine Location  - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                }else{
                    //wenn keine Location gefunden wurde
                    // GPS oder Netzwerk nicht verfügbar
                    // User fragen, ob er die Einstellungen ändern will 
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
            });


        btnEntfernung = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnDistance);

        btnEntfernung.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {    

                double x1,y1,x2,y2,radius;
                latitudeDB = Math.toRadians(48.569601);
                longitudeDB = Math.toRadians(16.572087);
                double entfernung=0;
                radius= 6378.137/360; 

                 x2=latitudeDB;
                 y2=longitudeDB;

                 x1=latitude;
                 y1=longitude;

                 double distanz =(x1-x2)+(y1-y2);   
                 double distanzfaktor = Math.acos((Math.sin(y1)*Math.sin(y2))+((Math.cos(y1)*Math.cos(y2))* (Math.cos(x2)-Math.cos(x1))));

                 if (distanz >=0){
                     entfernung = radius*distanzfaktor;
                 }
                 else if(distanz < 0){
                     entfernung = radius*(distanzfaktor + Math.PI);
                 }
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deine Entfernung" + entfernung + " km", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the built-in [`Location`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5b%5d%29) class to do this for you?

```
x2=latitudeDB;
y2=longitudeDB;

x1=latitude;
y1=longitude;

float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(x1, y1, x2, y2, results);
float distanceInMeters = results[0];

float distanceInKm = distanceInMeters / 1000.0f;

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deine Entfernung" + distanceInKm + " km", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I don't know how to use it, I'm just a beginner and it seems to be the easiest way :s but it's incorrect

Comment: Well I just showed you how to use it :) What do you mean it's incorrect? Are you sure your _other_ calculation is correct (if you think the result of the `Location` method is wrong)?

Comment: no no I'm sure that your code is correct, my code isn't it. But where should I copy it and how can I show the distance in a toast for example. I really thank you for your help. I'm not soo good in programming :s

Comment: I integrated my answer a little further into the code you provided.

Comment: Thank you really for your efforts, but I have 5255 km now :s

Comment: Oops, you're doing some conversion on those figures. Set `x2=48.569601;` and `y2=16.572087;`, I guess.

Comment: oh well, it works - thank you so much :-) now I have 21 km - perfect